# Pytest Flask rollback transactions after tests when using the Unit of Work pattern

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest, unit-of-work

I am studying the "Cosmic Python" book and chapter 6 explains how to use the Unit of Work pattern to change the interaction with the database/repository.

Chapter 6 of the book can be accessed here:
https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/chapter_06_uow.html

The code provided by the author is the following:

```
from __future__ import annotations
import abc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

from allocation import config
from allocation.adapters import repository


class AbstractUnitOfWork(abc.ABC):
    products: repository.AbstractRepository

    def __enter__(self) -> AbstractUnitOfWork:
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.rollback()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def commit(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def rollback(self):
        raise NotImplementedError



DEFAULT_SESSION_FACTORY = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(
    config.get_postgres_uri(),
    isolation_level="REPEATABLE READ",
))

class SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork(AbstractUnitOfWork):

    def __init__(self, session_factory=DEFAULT_SESSION_FACTORY):
        self.session_factory = session_factory

    def __enter__(self):
        self.session = self.session_factory()  # type: Session
        self.products = repository.SqlAlchemyRepository(self.session)
        return super().__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        super().__exit__(*args)
        self.session.close()

    def commit(self):
        self.session.commit()

    def rollback(self):
        self.session.rollback()
```

I am trying to test my endpoints on Flask but I could not make it rollback the data inserted after each test.

To solve that I tried to install the package `pytest-flask-sqlalchemy` but with the following error:

`'SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork' object has no attribute 'engine'`

I do not quite understand how `pytest-flask-sqlalchemy` works and I have no clue on how to make the Unit of Work rollback transactions after a test.

Is it possible to make it work the way the author implemented it?

## Edited

It is possible to replicate my situation through the following repository:

https://github.com/Santana94/CosmicPythonRollbackTest

You should get that the test is not rolling back previous actions by cloning it and running `make all`.

Comment: I cloned your repo and ran `make all` but got an error:

```/tests/e2e/test_api.py:32: in test_list_batches
    assert r.json() == []
E   AssertionError: assert equals failed
E     [                                   []
E       {
E         'id': 1,
E         'reference': 'batch--f3cd80',
E         'sku': 'sku--24eac1',
E       },
E       {                                                                    ...
```

Comment: OK I guess that's the point of your question LOL

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't commit `venv` to git.

Comment: After running `tests/e2e` the database contains test data
```allocation=# select * from allocations;
 id | orderline_id | batch_id
----+--------------+----------
 23 |           23 |       39
 25 |           25 |       42
```

Comment: This is exactly the point that I was looking to solve. The main problem is that every database change remains after the test finishes so that my test would not work until the rollback transaction would be implemented.

Comment: Oh right, I know I shouldn't commit the `venv` file, but it was just a quick test to a test repo so that people could help me on this issue.

Comment: Regarding the venv, I didn't mean to sound patronising :) Having it actually caused me problems because your commited one didn't work on my machine, so I had to `rm -f venv` and redo it.

Comment: I wasn' able to reproduce the error `'SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork' object has no attribute 'engine'`. How did you get that?

Comment: Oh right, I get that when I tried to use the package `pytest-flask-sqlalchemy`. But I removed it since it was not working in this implementation.

Comment: I think that it should be necessary to make a db_session fixture inside conftest to make tests drop the table content, something similar to this: Base.metadata.drop_all(engine). But I don't quite know how to do that.

Comment: >  I get that when I tried to use the package `pytest-flask-sqlalchemy`.

OK but how did you use that? :)

Comment: I have updated the master branch and now it has the problem that I was talking about.

Comment: If I add `def engine(self): raise RuntimeError('SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork.engine')` to `SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork` then the error becomes `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'connect'`

Comment: That's the problem when using the `pytest-flask-sqlalchemy` package to rollback transactions. It expects a sqlalchemy database and the unit of work pattern tries to make it in a different way.

Comment: I admit I find it hard to pin down the issue here, although the libs involved do interest me. The apporach I normally follow is try to separate concerns and come up with the simplest 'program' to replicate one issue (or one part of the issue).

Comment: I agree with you, it is hard and the normal procedure should be to implement DI to isolate everything and make objects easier to test. I am trying to mock the session from the class  `SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork` to try to make it rollback transactions.

Comment: I am trying to isolate the issue on the side of Flask + SqlAlchemy + Tests with rollback.

Comment: I think that I got the solution working. I managed to make the session rollback with a correction on `conftest.py`

Comment: Don't forget to post an answer to your own question once you find a working solution.

Comment: Absolutely! I am working on it and I will post it here as soon as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got to make the rollback functionality happen after every test.

I got that working when I saw a package called `pytest-postgresql` implementing it on itself. I just made my adjustments to make tests rollback the database data that I was working with. For that, I just had to implement this function on `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_session():
    engine = create_engine(config.get_postgres_uri(), echo=False, poolclass=NullPool)
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    pyramid_basemodel.Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
    pyramid_basemodel.bind_engine(
        engine, pyramid_basemodel.Session, should_create=True, should_drop=True)

    yield pyramid_basemodel.Session

    transaction.commit()
    metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

After that, I had to place the `db_session` as a parameter of a test if I wanted to rollback transactions:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('postgres_db')
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('restart_api')
def test_happy_path_returns_202_and_batch_is_allocated(db_session):
    orderid = random_orderid()
    sku, othersku = random_sku(), random_sku('other')
    earlybatch = random_batchref(1)
    laterbatch = random_batchref(2)
    otherbatch = random_batchref(3)
    api_client.post_to_add_batch(laterbatch, sku, 100, '2011-01-02')
    api_client.post_to_add_batch(earlybatch, sku, 100, '2011-01-01')
    api_client.post_to_add_batch(otherbatch, othersku, 100, None)

    r = api_client.post_to_allocate(orderid, sku, qty=3)
    assert r.status_code == 202

    r = api_client.get_allocation(orderid)
    assert r.ok
    assert r.json() == [
        {'sku': sku, 'batchref': earlybatch},
    ]
```

It is possible to check out the requirements for that and other aspects of that implementation on my GitHub repository.

https://github.com/Santana94/CosmicPythonRollbackTest